# Mysql and custom Icon in leafletjs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet

I am having a hard time getting leafletjs to use a custom icon via SQL data.

I have gotten polygons to use SQL defined colors, but every time I try to use the same method with `{icon: }` I end up with
`jQuery.Deferred exception: t.icon.createIcon is not a function TypeError: t.icon.createIcon is not a function`

Trying to set the SQL data as a var hasn't worked either
`var myicon = companies[i]['type']`

However calling `companies[i]['type']` in the popup works fine and displays the data.

In the database the field is called `type` and is formatted as a string as `gasIcon` or `defaIcon` etc, so that when it gets called it matches the different icons.

Here is the marker code.

```
function addCompanies() {
  var TypeIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
      shadowUrl: './images/type-shadow.png',
      iconSize: [33, 44],
      shadowSize: [36, 39],
      iconAnchor: [17, 44],
      shadowAnchor: [0, 50],
      popupAnchor: [-3, -50]
    }
  });
  var gasIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/gasIcon.png'
      }),
      ammuIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/ammuIcon.png'
      }),
      copsIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/copsIcon.png'
      }),
      carsIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/carsIcon.png'
      }),
      bankIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/bankIcon.png'
      }),
      defaIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/defaIcon.png'
      }),
      hospIcon = new TypeIcon({
        iconUrl: './images/hospIcon.png'
      });

  for (var i = 0; i < companies.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker([
      companies[i]['latitude'], 
      companies[i]['longitude']
    ],{
      icon: companies[i]['type']
    }).addTo(map);

    marker.bindPopup("<b>" + 
                     companies[i]['company'] + "-" + 
                     companies[i]['type'] + 
                     "</b><br>Details:" + 
                     companies[i]['details'] + 
                     "<br />Telephone: " + 
                     companies[i]['telephone']);
  }
}
```

Don't understand why `icon: companies[i]['type']` Doesn't work but `color: areas[i]['color']` does.

Much appreciated, and this is my first time asking here so I apologize if I didn't leave enough information to help find an answer, but will post more if needed.

Comment: What is the value of `companies[i]['type']`? Is is a string, or an instance of `L.Icon`?

Comment: Depending on what radio button selected when adding it to the DB, it can be  
`gasIcon
ammuIcon
copsIcon
carsIcon
bankIcon
hospIcon
defaIcon`  
All of which are stored as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, the value of `companies[i]['type']` is a string. It does not become a variable and, in this case, a reference to any of the icons. This is why it works in the popup text too, if you'd put an icon reference into the popup text you'd get something that reads `[object Object]`, not very useful.

The result of this is then `icon: "gasIcon"` and not `icon: gasIcon`.

To fix this you could put your icons into an object like so:

```
var icons = {
    gasIcon: new TypeIcon({iconUrl: './images/gasIcon.png'}),
    ammuIcon: new TypeIcon({iconUrl: './images/ammuIcon.png'}),
    copsIcon: new TypeIcon({iconUrl: './images/copsIcon.png'})
}
```

Then you can get a working icon reference like this:

```
icon: icons[companies[i]['type']]
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Gyjl3MFmsC8g4yPS8n5V?p=preview

Comment: Worked like a charm, and taught me something too. Thank you.